# an unknown error occured while processing request to facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i'm trying to send some likes on facebook page post but for firstt time i notice that error and don't know the reason
request:
https://graph.facebook.com/479322648852908/likes?access_token=CAAEYj0oZAmMsBAHmBWezCtiPfBZAHnOTyzblZB1YxvBbXFZC88ybqS2LlNTwWdsKRECdqZC7A1WEnSVqZCSlt0ftAs8YYmrLtJurIfd5BIotlf1DdMymD1ZBBF9ayYlLrCs1h7JHkRP6PZBv6M2oQpjWVoKPYTufdgdagto3blt2styL2XpYFBsVdmwlmNEQOBwZD&method=POST

```
Response:
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#1) An unknown error occurred",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 1
   }
}
```

Any hint ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get away without the access token via the url:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/479322648852908/likes
```

Comment: i'm not getting the likes data of post ,BUT i send like to that post via api
METHOD=POST

Comment: Hmmm, If I load that url in a browser I see a JSON user list.

Comment: He doesn't really want to fetch the number of likes, but like a page/post instead.